# Topics in Geometry and Dynamical Systems

Tags: geometry, soft-question, dynamical-systems, book-recommendation, complex-dynamics

Dynamical Systems/Fractal Geometry and Differential Geometry/Topology are really interesting areas of study. My question is whether there is any direct connection between them? In other words, are there research topics that lie in between them and require tools from both areas?
If so, any recommendation for articles or even textbooks on such topics?

Comment: Try the book [Geometric Theory of Dynamical Systems - An Introduction](http://www.springer.com/br/book/9781461257059).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Dynamics: The Geometry of Behavior (2nd edition)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201567172) is very nice illustrated introduction.

The [1st edition](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0942344022) came out in four volumes.

See also the recommendations in [Good books on Geometric Theory of Dynamical Systems](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/149879/good-books-on-geometric-theory-of-dynamical-systems).